Any solutions to keep timer running in android app widget after app was closed or killed
I'm trying to implement a countdown timer in a an app widget, but after user closes app timer stops updating.
I tried to use AlarmManager with a BrodcastService but it's not working . When app closed timer doesn't update.
I need to update it every monute.

"a countdown timer in a widget" -- by "widget", do you mean what the documentation refers to as an app widget?

Yes, an app widget

To update an app widget every minute, you would need to keep a process running all the time, such as via a foreground service. Users really dislike developers that do this, because it wastes RAM and battery life.

But how can I do it ? Any examples from someone who did it ? Because I tried with a service and alarm manager but it's not working
